# How must the prototype of this function look like to be compilable?

Tags: c, prototype, compiler-errors

I have this code:

```
void PrintMainParameters(int n, char* array[])
{
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
   printf("%s \n", array[i]);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  PrintMainParameters(argc, argv);
}
```

Works fine. Now I want to write PrintMainParameters as prototype to declare the function later in the source file.

I tried this one, but it says type mismatch, that the second parameter is an incompatible pointer type. I understand the compiler error, but I do not know why it occurs.

```
void PrintMainParameters(int, char*);


int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
 PrintMainParameters(argc, argv);
}

void PrintMainParameters(int n, char* array[])
{
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
   printf("%s \n", array[i]);
  }
}
```

How must the prototype look like? Why does my code not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either:

```
void PrintMainParameters(int, char**);
```

or:

```
void PrintMainParameters(int, char *[]);
```

Or if you prefer, you can insert a dummy parameter into the prototype, such as:

```
void PrintMainParameters(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

Comment: +1 for the last option, which greatly improves the readability for anyone looking at only the prototype.

Answer (score 6):

Your function takes an array of char pointers. Your prototype declares it to take a single char pointer instead. The correct prototype looks like this:

```
void PrintMainParameters(int, char*[]);
```